# asp.net databind label control text to property of page baseclass

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Why is TestString is always empty when I try to output it into my Label?

Base class for all asp.net pages

```
public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string TestString { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
TestString = "test string";
}
```

asp.net page that derives from PageBase and uses a master page.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text="<%# this.TestString %>" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you are setting TestString in code that you are not showing?

Comment: Code updated to show TestString being set :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The code below doesn't actually work—I tested it, just not well.  What OP was really looking for was:

```
<div id="lblContent"><%= this.TestString %></div>
```

---

I think you need to change this

```
<asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text="<%# this.TestString %>" />
```

to this

```
<asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text="<%= this.TestString %>" />
```

<%# just runs code, but doesn't **output** anything.  <%= will output whatever is inside those tags.

Comment: If I change it to the = tag, I get the message "This is not scriptlet. Will be output as plain text" and it does output as text.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to either set the Text property of the label in the code behind, or ditch the label and put a regular div tag in there, with a <%= in the middle.

Comment: Good call. Just removing the Label control and writing it directly works great.

Comment: @JonC - great, glad it worked.  BTW, for what it's worth, I *did* test the code I put up there, well, sort of.  I put my own label in my code like this  <asp:Label><%= this.SomeText %></asp:Label>  which does work, but is missing the runat='server' tag.  I missed that, assumed it would work your way, and just changed your code.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `DataBind()` method.

In page_load handler,

```
TestString="Testing a property";
lblContent.DataBind();
//or
DataBind();
```

Comment: I can't call lblContent from the PageBase class.    
I also tried 
    ((Label) this.FindControl("lblContent")).Text = "TEST";

Comment: @JonC - You may invoke DataBind() method of page/parent control.

Comment: I would rather avoid this since I would have to do it on every page, this is why I wanted to abstract to the base class