# Exclude some fields from class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data class of 20 `decimal` fields and another of 20 `string` fields.  I populate both classes from SQL calls then use the values to populate labels on a web page.

```
public class MyDecimals
{
    public decimal MyDecimal1 { get; set; }
    public decimal MyDecimal2 { get; set; }
    public decimal MyDecimal3 { get; set; }
    public decimal MyDecimal4 { get; set; }
    public decimal MyDecimal5 { get; set; }
    public decimal MyDecimal6 { get; set; }
    .
    .
    public decimal MyDecimal20 { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MyDecimalsNames
{
    public string MyDecimal1Name { get; set; }
    public string MyDecimal2Name { get; set; }
    public string MyDecimal3Name { get; set; }
    public string MyDecimal4Name { get; set; }
    public string MyDecimal5Name { get; set; }
    public string MyDecimal6Name { get; set; }
    .
    .
    public string MyDecimal20Name { get; set; }
}
```

On the `aspx` page the labels are named like `lblMyDecimal1`,`lblMyDecimal1Name`,`lblMyDecimal2`, `lblMyDecimal2Name`.....

Rather than code the label values line by line like this ...

```
lblMyDecimal1.Text = myClass.MyDecimal1.ToString("#,##0");
lblMyDecimal1Name.Text = myNamesClass.MyDecimal1Name;
lblMyDecimal2.Text = myClass.MyDecimal2.ToString("#,##0");
lblMyDecimal2Name.Text = myNamesClass.MyDecimal2Name;
```

I am trying to loop through the fields in the class and assign the label values based on the field name:

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myClass))
{
    ((Label)FindControl("lbl" + prop.Name)).Text = prop.GetValue(myClass).ToString("#,##0");
}
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myNameClass))
{
    ((Label)FindControl("lbl" + prop.Name)).Text = prop.GetValue(myNameClass) + "";
}
```

This would work as I want, however at the moment I only have labels 1 - 12, 13 - 20 are not used on this particular page.

So my question is: What is the best way for me to skip the fields/labels that are not on the page?

I know I could create a list of excludes and test each value for not in list but I would like to exclude them before that as if they are not in the class in the first place if possible.

Comment: If they're in the class, they're in the class. Best you can do is use a custom attribute to exclude them or modify the code to check for index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check whether the label exists:

```
if (FindControl("lbl" + prop.Name) != null) { ... }
```

Or [use databinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373262/asp-net-databind-label-control-text-to-property-of-page-baseclass).